# How to execute a command after setting environment by running shell script?

Tags: shell, ansible

I am connecting to a remote Linux machine using ansible. I want to execute an application specific command which will give me application version.But before that, a shell script has to be executed which will set the environment for the above command execution.

Currently, each task is executed in separate shell it seems

I want to execute `psadmin -v`, after executing `/ds1/home/has9e/CS9/psconfig.sh`:

```
- command: "{{ item }}"
  args:
    chdir: "/ds1/home/has9e/CS9/"
  with_items:
   - "./psconfig.sh"
   - "psadmin -v"
  register:  ptversion
  ignore_errors: true
```

Error is:

```
failed: [slc13rog] (item=./psconfig.sh) => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "./psconfig.sh",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "./psconfig.sh",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": "/ds1/home/has9e/CS9/",
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "item": "./psconfig.sh",
    "msg": "[Errno 8] Exec format error",
    "rc": 8
}
```

Comment: can you paste here your code ? Did you try 'shell' module inside the playbook ?Your requirement is clear but without what u have done so far its bit complected to help

Comment: Please find my task below 
    - command: "{{ item }}"
      args:
        chdir: "/ds1/home/has9e/CS9/"
      with_items:
       - "./psconfig.sh"
       - "psadmin -v"
      register:  ptversion
      ignore_errors: true

Comment: try shell instead of command module.Like below 
- shell: "{{ item }}" args: chdir: "/ds1/home/has9e/CS9/" with_items: - "./psconfig.sh" - "psadmin -v" register: ptversion ignore_errors: true

Answer (score 0):

The `command` module (and the `shell` module) execute your command in a child process.  This means that if you run a shell script that sets environment variables, that has **no effect** on any subsequent commands: the variables are set in the child process, which then exits.

If you want the environment variables set in a shell script to effect a subsequent command, you need to make them both part of the same shell script.  For example:

```
- shell: |
    ./psconfig.sh
    psadmin -v
  args:
    chdir: "/ds1/home/has9e/CS9/"
  register:  ptversion
  ignore_errors: true
```

Here, we're using the YAML `|` operator to pass a literal block to the `shell` module, but we could have written instead:

```
- shell: "./psconfig.sh;psadmin -v"
  args:
    chdir: "/ds1/home/has9e/CS9/"
  register:  ptversion
  ignore_errors: true
```

The two alternatives are functionally identical. In both cases, we are sourcing the `psconfig.sh` script into the shell environment, and then running the `psadmin` task **in the same shell**.

Comment: I understood the question in that way, that he wants to execute the commands in different ssh connections, because the first has an impact on the second.

Comment: Thanks. By the method you suggested,I tried to print the environment variables from same shell with and without running psadmin.sh. But both environment variables look same, means the shell doesnt have the variables exported by scrit
 
Without psadmin.sh
----------------------------
    - shell: "env"
      args:
        chdir: "/ds1/home/has9e/CS9/"
      register:  ptversion
      ignore_errors: true
With psadmin.sh
-----------------------
    - shell: "./psconfig.sh;env"
      args:
        chdir: "/ds1/home/has9e/CS9/"
      register:  ptversion
      ignore_errors: true

Comment: Can you update your question to show the contents of `psconfig.sh`? Please don't post that as a comment, because it's not possible to format code in comments legibly.